# ADB restore isn't working

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat, backup, nexus-5, restore

I think there are a lot of this type of questions but I have a new (for me and can't find it anywhere) problem with the `adb restore` command.

I created an `adb backup -apk -shared -all` and it looked like it worked and I think it did because the size is 6 GB. Well I made this from Android L Preview because I wanted to downgrade because of the bugs (I hope they fix them) and when I try to restore it on Android KitKat 4.4.4 it is not working, the `adb shell logcat -s BackupManagerService`returned this when I tried to make a full restore:

`I/BackupManagerService(  758): Beginning full restore...
D/BackupManagerService(  758): Starting restore confirmation UI, token=1224340204
D/BackupManagerService(  758): Waiting for full restore completion...
D/BackupManagerService(  758): acknowledgeFullBackupOrRestore : token=1224340204 allow=true
D/BackupManagerService(  758): Sending conf message with verb 10
I/BackupManagerService(  758): --- Performing full-dataset restore ---
I/BackupManagerService(  758): Initiating bind of OBB service on com.android.server.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection@437913f8
I/BackupManagerService(  758): OBB service connection com.android.internal.backup.IObbBackupService$Stub$Proxy@43ad7c48 connected on com.android.server.BackupManagerService$FullBackupObbConnection@437913f8
W/BackupManagerService(  758): Wrong header version: 3
W/BackupManagerService(  758): Invalid restore data; aborting.
I/BackupManagerService(  758): Full restore processing complete.
D/BackupManagerService(  758): Full restore pass complete.`

Is there a fix for this? Or another way to restore this information? The backup is encrypted but there is not an error of a wrong password and I am pretty sure it's the correct password.

Thank you for your time and I hope you can help me solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't restore a backup made from a higher Android version onto a lower Android version. This can be seen from the line `W/BackupManagerService(  758): Wrong header version: 3`. ADB backups should always be restored onto the same version (or higher, not sure about this).

Comment: I thought it could be that but I am a little new on this so I needed to check that with some other people, thanks for the answer but tell me something, is there a way to make a Backup of a newer Android version and restore it on an older one? And to understand more, what's the header version? How could I understand the number next to it? Thanks!